# How to add Iframe to my Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I am developing facebook application.I want to add iframe to my facebook page.I don't have any idea ,how to do it.I know we can not create a page using graph api or any api in facebook.

Comment: I recommend marking this and some of your other questions as answered. It's part of being in the SO community.

Answer (score 2):

All the information you need is here - found by a quick google search:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/iframe/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need your own hosting server which have HTTPS, and create your page with the language that they support and place the link points directly to the folder to facebook app setting. make sure your width does not go beyonds 520px for facebook custom tab page. if apps u can go up to 760px.

Hope that helps